# How to remove file from the queue to stop upload before upload starts in blueimp Basic?

Tags: jquery, blueimp

Here is the thing,

I want cancel button similar to Basic plus UI or jQuery UI in **Basic**. This question might look silly to you. But actually i got confuse from template which blueimp are using in Basic plus UI or jQuery UI to list upload and downloaded file with start, delete and cancel button.

**EDIT 1 here:** Even i can't use that template because i am working in twig template, which has similar syntax which give error if i use.

I need code to remove file from the queue and to prevent upload before upload start.

I searched that _cancelHandler is in jquery.fileupload-ui.js but there are lots of function which are making me confuse.

Please someone help.

Even i read basic use of plugin in documentation (minimal setup guide) but there is not data to have cancel button.

**EDIT 2 here :** I think i missed to tell that i need only single upload button which will upload all the files which are in queue. if any file in the list cancelled then that should not upload.

**here is my code**

```
$(function () {

    var cancel_btn = $('<button/>')
    .addClass('btn btn-warning cancel pull-right')
    .html('<i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i><span> Cancel')
    .on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        data = $this.data();
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();

        alert("code to remove from the queue and to prevent upload before upload start");
    });

    var delete_btn = $('<button/>')
    .addClass('btn btn-danger cancel pull-right')
    .html('<i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i><span> Delete')
    .on('click', function () {
        alert('code needed to delete file');
    });    

    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        add: function (e, data) {

            console.log(data);
           // data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {

                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                var td1 = document.createElement('td');
                var td2 = document.createElement('td');
                var td3 = document.createElement('td');
                $(td1).append(file.name);
                $(td2).append(file.size);
                $(td3).append(cancel_btn.clone(true).data(data));
                $(tr).append(td1,td2,td3);
                $('#files_list tbody').append(tr);

                var size = $('#files_list tbody tr').size();
                if(size < 1 )
                    $('#files_list').addClass('hide');
                else
                    $('#files_list').removeClass('hide');
            });

            $('#submit').click(function (){
                //data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));
                data.submit();
                $('#files_list tbody').html('');
            });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {

            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                var td1 = document.createElement('td');
                var td2 = document.createElement('td');
                var td3 = document.createElement('td');
                $(td1).append(file.name);
                $(td2).append(file.size);
                $(td3).append(delete_btn.clone(true).data(data));
                $(tr).append(td1,td2,td3);
                $('#files_list tbody').append(tr);
            });
        },
        fail: function (e, data) {
            //console.log(data.result);
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                var error = $('<span/>').text(file.error);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(error);
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add an "upload" and "cancel" button to every file and bind the submit function on these buttons.

```
var cancel_btn = $('<button/>')
    .addClass('btn btn-warning cancel pull-right')
    .html('<i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i><span> Cancel')
var upload_btn = $('<button/>')
    .addClass('btn btn-warning upload pull-right')
    .html('<i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i><span> Upload')
    });
 $('#submit').on('click',function(){
     $('.upload').click() //click upload buttons and upload all files in the queue
 })
 $('#cancel').on('click',function(){
     $('.cancel').click() //click cancel buttons and remove all files in the queue
 })
 .......
 $('#files_list tbody').append(tr);
 $(td4).append(upload_btn.clone(true).data(data));
 $('.upload').eq(-1).on('click',function(){//button to upload only this file
      data.submit();
 })
 $('.cancel').eq(-1).on('click',function(){
      $(this).parent().parent().remove()//or something like this, 
                                        //delete the whole <tr> 
                                        //and remove the file from the queue
 })
```

Comment: if you want just a single button, hide the `.upload` buttons

Comment: But the answer you gave me , does not full filled my requirement. :(

Comment: if you want we can talk in the chat, because I think my answer does what you want http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10158/blueimp

Comment: Thanks man! Wasted half a day trying to figure out how to modify the array with files to be uploaded.

Comment: So if I'm following this correctly, there's no way to unbind just one click event from a 'Submit All' button? So we're cheating a little and making the 'Submit All' button click each of the individual 'Upload' buttons? and then we simply remove the 'Upload' button to remove the file from the queue?

Comment: @AndrewBrown yes, exactly.