# Blueimp fileuplad - how to remove a file from the queue before upload

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I am using Blueimp fileupload for uploading images in my project. After i load up the images, I want to place a button for the each image which can be pressed to clear it from the upload queue before the upload (like the one from the plugin's demo page@ http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). I've looked everywhere I can't seem to find a solution that actually works for me.... Here's the code I've been using...

```
   $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
imageMaxWidth: 1000,
imageMaxHeight: 800,
    previewMaxWidth: 100,
    previewMaxHeight: 100,
    previewCrop: false
}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    //Add buttons for canceling individual images
$("#uploadBttn").click(function () {
                data.submit();
    });
}).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
    var index = data.index, 
        file = data.files[index];
    if (file.preview) {
        $("#imgPreview").append(file.preview);
    }
}).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
$('#progress .bar').css('width',progress + '%');
}).on('fileuploadstart', function (e) {
$("#uploadBttn").unbind().prop('disabled', true).text('Uploading...');
}).on('fileuploadstop', function (e) {
$("#uploadBttn").text('Done!');
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove file from the queue to stop upload before upload starts in blueimp Basic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267958/how-to-remove-file-from-the-queue-to-stop-upload-before-upload-starts-in-blueimp)

Comment: Yes. I did see that question, and tried it for my stuff. Although this removes the file entry from the table, it didn't actually remove it from the upload queue. So when I click on the upload button, it ends up uploading everything including the ones that I removed from the table.

Comment: add also a button for every single file and bind the submit on it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set the context of your file to the table row, and then do something like this:

```
$("#uploadBttn").click(function () {
    if (data.context.is(":visible"))
        data.submit();
});
```