# Blueimp File Upload: Remove a file from file list before upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

How can I remove a file from the selected files list in Blueimp plugins before submitting the form to upload. I tried [**this SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267958/how-to-remove-file-from-the-queue-to-stop-upload-before-upload-starts-in-blueimp) but its just remove file from UI not from queue.

Here is my code

```
$(function(){
            $("#UploadPhotos").click(function(){
                $("#ItemPhotos").click();
            });
            $('#ItemPhotos').fileupload({
                    url: "${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/XYZ",
                    //dataType: 'json',
                    autoUpload: false,
                    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
                    maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
                    // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
                    // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
                    // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
                    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
                    previewMaxWidth: 171,
                    singleFileUploads:false,
                    previewMaxHeight: 180,
                    previewCrop: true
                }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
                    data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#FilesListThumb');
                    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                        var node = $('<div><h6>X</h6></div>').addClass("thumbnail-ib");
                        node.appendTo(data.context);
                        node.find("h6").click(function(){
                            node.remove();
                        });
                    });
                    $("#itemSellForm").submit(function(){
                        data.formData = $("#itemSellForm").serializeArray();
                        data.submit();
                        return false;
                    });                        
                }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
                    var index = data.index,
                        file = data.files[index],
                        node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
                    if (file.preview) {
                        node
                            .addClass("thumbnail")
                            .append(file.preview);
                    }
                    if (file.error) {
                        node
                            .addClass("thumbnail")
                            .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text("Upload Failed"));
                    }
                }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
                    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                        var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
                        $(data.context.children()[index])
                            .append('<br>')
                            .append(error);
                    });
                }).on("fileuploaddone",function(e,data){
                  //  sendData = false;
                 alert("done");
                });
        });
```

here when I click h6 thumbnail is removed from ui only not from the list of ifles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every BlueImp callback have 2 parameters: an `event` and a `data` object.

The `data` object contains a `files` array which you can edit in order to alter files that will be uploaded. So if you delete one of these array elements (`array.pop`, or other methods...) before submitting your request, it can be considered as *removed*.

Comment: Oh yes it worked i added `data.files.splice(index,1);` inside `node.find("h6").click`

Comment: Be careful, I think the index of the data.files array is recalculate when you delete one of the object in the middle of the array.

Comment: so what care should i take.if i delete an element from data.files it recalculate the index.So i think its Ok cos next time again when I click delete button it will take index from new recalculated array.Right?

Comment: One more thing in my case can u tell me how to remove all files from queue after submit form?

Comment: @Manish If you add 3 file at once, then you delete them from the 1-indexed to the last indexed, the `index` value on your `splice` function won't be updated. To check it just write a `console.log(index)` and test it.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: @Manish Maybe add in your `<h6>` node the name of the file (or an auto-incremented id, or a timestamp, or a unique token, ...) in order to identify the file? And maybe you could re-use this id to remove success updated file from the queue?

Comment: @Manish You should ask a new question about this specific sub-problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe helps additionally click event(s) for button UploadPhotos to delete/unbind.

```
$("#UploadPhotos").unbind("click")
```